# Prerender redirection for root path don't work

Tags: apache, prerender

I'm configuring my apache server to handle prerender's middleware, it works well actually except for the root path.

When i try to crawl **www.example.com?_escaped_fragment_**, it return **www.example.com/** but the prerender middleware is not reached.

Others page like www.example.com/foo?_escaped_fragment_ works fine.

Here is my apache configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin ***
    ServerName example.com
            ServerAlias www.example.com

    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/current/web

    LogLevel warn

    <Directory /var/www/example/current/web>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex app.php

    ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html

    <Location />
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule .? - [L]

        # Catch all request if crawler and redirect to Prerender server
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Google(.*)|Facebot|googlebot|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
        RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(app\.php)?(.*) http://prerender.example/https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]

        # Catch all request if we are on maintenance
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|jpg|png)$
        RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.html -f
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !maintenance.html
        RewriteRule ^.*$  -  [redirect=503,last]

        # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
        RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_alias.c>
            RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does it work if you move the Prerender rewrite rule above that first rewrite rule for a file? Your app.php might be served there when requesting your homepage.

Comment: Thank you @Prerender.io, i moved the the prerender rules to the first position, and it works !